# Kernel messages on console

Tags: linux-kernel

I just got the following messages on the console:

```
Message from syslogd@andromeda at Dec  5 12:50:47 ...
 kernel:page:ffffea003ae93000 count:3 mapcount:0 mapping:ffff9986dc372810 index:0x7000000000000180

Message from syslogd@andromeda at Dec  5 12:50:47 ...
 kernel:flags: 0xe02ffffc00000829(locked|uptodate|lru|private)
```

I am slightly surprised since they don't point to a bug or error. They just seem to give some kind of information but I have no idea what to do with it. Any suggestions about what this means?

This is running on Fedora 25:

```
$ uname -r
4.8.10-300.fc25.x86_64
```

Comment: +1 Quite odd I agree. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/unevictable-lru.txt